# Django is_staff flag resets every time user log in

Tags: django, ldap, django-admin, django-users

How to set is_staff flag permanently?
I have LDAP connected to my Django app.
When i set up is_staff flag in admin panel its all ok but when this user relogs it is changed back to no-flag.
Is there any way to prevent changing it back and set is_staff flag permanently?

Comment: How did you connect LDAP to Django?

Comment: with django_auth_ldap